# Opening a tight cap of a bottle of water

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, friction

Just a curious question that came to my mind a few days ago. Say we have a tight cap of a bottle of water, we know that the kinetic friction force is smaller than static friction, so then I thought, would the cap be opened easier if we rotate the cap back and then forth to open it (kinetic friction) than if we just try to open it from static?

I don't know if I'm being clear enough, but essentially I'm wondering if rotating a cap back and forth would help in opening the cap as it would activate kinetic friction force, or at least that's what I think

Comment: It's not clear how you're going to rotate it and skip over the static friction part. It's necessary to first overcome the static friction at any time here.